# Prevent TS errors when importing untyped JS

Tags: typescript

I am getting the following Typescript error in a React application when attempting to import untyped JS functions:

```
Variable 'initialiseConfig' implicitly has type 'any' in some locations where its type cannot be determined.  TS7034
```

Is there a way to prevent TS getting upset about certain imported, untyped JS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `require` statement instead of `import ... from` when importing libraries that doesn't have type declaration.